# Is autosave to localStorage regularly and frequently bad?

Tags: javascript, database, save, local-storage, storage

I made a simple web app that lets you create as many stopwatches as you want. Every stopwatch is an object that has a name, an ID, the elapsed time, and some HTML elements. You can individually run or stop any of the stopwatches.

I have an idea where if the user closes the tab, the browser, or refreshes, every stopwatch and its properties will be saved. So when the user refreshes or leaves and comes back to the website, all the stopwatches will still be there in the correct order, with the correct name, correct ID, and displaying the same elapsed time as when they had left. However, if a user leaves the page and comes back, all the stopwatches will be paused even if it was running before the session ended (I assume this will make things easier for me to program).

There are a few ways that I am thinking of doing this. I can save to localStorage every second or if that's too resource-intensive, then maybe every 5 seconds? Alternatively, I can create a manual save button but I don't quite like that idea as much. Lastly, I'm not familiar with database storage, but could that possibly be better? Is there a better way to do this that I am not aware of?

In my mind, the best solution is an autosave every second to localStorage, but is that a resource-intensive procedure?

Comment: I don't think using localStorage that way is very resource intensive. Check and play with [this page](https://js-ow8zun.stackblitz.io/)

Answer (score 1):

Local storage is resource-intensive, but still, if you go for any DATABASE then you need an authentication mechanism and backend code to communicate. So for your current purpose local-storage is fine. But in the future better consider backend API to save and retrieve data from the database and use service workers for offline-online syncing with backend.